# All my views are strongly typed, how to pass to site.master?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My views all use strongly typed viewmodels.

Now in my controllers action, I want to set a warning text that will display in my site.master file.

If I set the text in my controllers action, how will it be visible in the site.master?

I'm confused b/c the strongly typed view for the master will be different.

(MVC2)

**Update**

Also, if I am redirecting to another view, even if I set the viewmodel it will not be used because it is redirect, **I know mvc has some sort of a single page session, what is that called again?**

Comment: can you not use an interface? for eaxmple: IView

Answer (score 2):

For all of my Strongly Typed ViewModels, I use a common base class and interface for this. By default the master page gets them.

```
public class ViewModelBase : IViewModel {
    public string InformationForMasterPage{get;set;}
}
public class ViewModelHomePage : ViewModelBase{
    public string SomeInformationNotNeededForMasterPage{get;set;}
}
public interface IViewModel{
    public string InformationForMasterPage{get;set;}
}
```

At the Top of the Home Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ViewModelHomePage>" %
```

Then for the top of the Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<IViewModel>" %>
```

And then deep in the master page:

```
 <%: Model.InformationForMasterPage %>
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you can save the object in either the `ViewData` or `ViewBag` dictionaries and access it from both the view and the master.

Comment: but viewdata will not work if I am doing a `return redirecttoaction` right? I have to use the viewbag?